# Adding a registry key in windows with quotes

Tags: windows, powershell, command-prompt

I need to create an REG ADD to use in a bat file but the problem is when I try to add the "%1" value. Yes, the value needs to be inside the double quotes.

```
REG ADD HKCR\advlaunch\shell\open\command /ve /t REG_SZ /d "\"C:\scripts\Advantage_Start_Process.exe\" \"%1\"" /f
```

But I got a syntax error when I try this.

The Value must be like this.
[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9560709/adding-a-registry-key-in-windows-with-quotes-needed-in-the-data-using-a-batch-sc/9561686#9561686

Comment: I tried this, even copying the same code, and didn't work, that's why I started this new thread.

Comment: Have you tried this at a cmd.exe command prompt?

Comment: Yep, for now I'm trying at CMD before trying at batch file.

Comment: It works for me, but not in powershell.

Comment: You need to double the % character when executed from a batch file: REG ADD "\"C:\scripts\Advantage_Start_Process.exe\" \"%%1\""

Comment: Double % worked for me in batch file but not via CMD, funny behavior, haha. Tks guys.

Comment: I think you're running powershell not cmd.